# angularjs ui.routes modules html5mode works or not?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I've googled a little bit but I 
found very little information if
ui.routes works or not with 
html5mode=true and $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
I mean if you use ui-router you can make your site
crawlable by ie google ?
Can you give me a hint, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ui.router` does work with `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');` It will use HTML5 mode when the browser supports it, or fall back to hashbang if there is no support.  The hashbang will look something like:

```
http://www.mysite.com/#!/mydirectory/file.html
```

You will also need to include a meta tag to help google know about the URL fragment

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

Doing all of this helps search engines determine how to access your precompiled content, but you will still need to generate and supply it.  Here is some good information on how the SEO part will work if you haven't already seen this: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification?hl=fr-FR

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in your sitemap you can include the pages you want the search providers to crawl.

For instance either of these would be acceptable:

```
http://www.example.com/!/colorwheel/green
http://www.example.com/colorwheel/green
```

In a sitemap.xml it would look like this:

```
<url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/colorwheel/green/</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>1.00</priority>
</url>
```